# C# Visual Studio 2012, how to show class members and methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Im searching for a window where I can browse through my C#-Classes.
In Java and Netbeans I always had a nice window, with which I could navigate through all the methods.

I think I had it opened once, but cant find it anymore. 
Already tried all Windows in Tab "View".

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View -> Class View (Ctrl + W, C)

Comment: thats sort of what I was looking for :) ty

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't of tried them all...

I think the one you want is: "View" > "Class View" (<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>)

There is also "Solution Explorer", which is what I prefer to use for navigation (<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **Class view (Ctrl+W,C)**

or for complete solution **solution explorer(Ctrl+W,S)** or

Both of them are available under view--> Solution Explorer and view-->Class View

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl + ,` to browse and navigate to all `classes` , `methods`and `properties` fast . add `.cs` after the name to search only for classes.